# Using Lists and String methods to sensor out words in python

Tags: python

I am working on a program to sensor out words in python. 
user input = my email id is harry@hogwarts.com
output     = my email id is xxxxx@hogwarts.com

this is what i have so far

```
def main():
    message = []
    userInput = str(input("Enter the sentence: "))
    splitInput = str(list(userInput))
    print(splitInput)
    for item in splitInput:
        indeces = splitInput.index('@')
        while((indeces-1).isalpha()):
            item = 'x'
            message.append(item)
    print(' '.join(message))
```

this is the error i get

```
File "C:\Users\Manmohit\Desktop\purifier.py", line 8, in main
    while((indeces-1).isalpha()):
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isalpha'
```

i have tried looking online for different methods. I want somthing similar to is alpha method. Should i write my own alpha method to check or can i use something inbuilt???
Help is appreciated. Thank you

UPDATES :

on changing the loop `while((indeces-1).isalpha()):` to `while((str(indeces-1)).isalpha()):` i dont get the error but i dont get any output as well.

Comment: it's hogwarts, not hogwards :)

Comment: just an example. Excuse the spellings.

Comment: The message is very expressive: an integer does not have an attribute isalpha. The thing before .isalpha is an integer. Why would you want to call it on that?

Comment: i want to go back every character until it reaches a non alpha character. I thought that would work.

Comment: But your characters are inside splitInput...

Comment: @möter i split the input so that i could find the "@" easily and go back one character at a time. Is that a wrong approach? i am still new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this function to encode email:

```
>>> def encodeemail(email):
       e = email.split("@")
       return "@".join(["x" * len(e[0]), e[1]])

>>> encodeemail("harry@hogwarts.com")
xxxxx@hogwarts.com
```

or even

```
>>> def encodeemail(email):
        d = email.split(" ")
        for i, f in enumerate(d):
            e = f.split("@")
            if len(e) > 1: d[i] = "@".join(["x" * len(e[0]), e[1]])
    return " ".join(d)

>>> encodeemail("this is harry@hogwarts.com")
this is xxxxx@hogwarts.com
```

without enumerate:

```
>>> def encodeemail(email):
        d = email.split(" ")
        for i in range(len(d)):
            e = d[i].split("@")
            if len(e) > 1: d[i] = "@".join(["x" * len(e[0]), e[1]])
    return " ".join(d)
```

Comment: Thats very short and useful. Thank you

Comment: the problem is it will blank out everything before it
Eg if i do encodeemail(this is me@me.com)
output i belive will be 'xxxxxxxxxx@me.com'
where as i want the output to be 'this is xx@me.com'

Comment: thanks for accepting, but take a look at zhangyangyu answer with regexp.

Comment: That works perfectly. Just a small query. Is there a way i can not use enumerate? can it be done differently?

Comment: added version withour enumerate

Comment: Thanks !! that helps alot. Makes easy for me to understand. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module if the string does not contain email only.

```
>>> s
'my email id is harry@hogwards.com'
>>> re.sub('(?<=\s)\w+(?=@)', lambda y: 'x'*len(y.group()), s)
'my email id is xxxxx@hogwards.com'
```

Comment: Yes, no need for `\s`.

Comment: can somebody explain me the above ??

Comment: You may want to read the [re doc](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). As for this regex, it means replace all the characters before @ with some x. \w means a-zA-z0-9_.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to check if a part of the string passes or fails the isalpha() test.  That isn't what your code is doing.

While there may be better ways to solve your problem, you can also make your code work.  Hopefully that is useful.

```
while((indeces-1).isalpha()):
```

indeces is an integer, as is -1, so the result of what you are applying isalpha to is an int, as the error says.

```
(str(indeces-1)).isalpha()
```

This doesn't work either.  That is making a string out of the int, so str(2) results in "2", which isn't the test you want either.

If you want to check the character, just index into the string, like so:

```
>>> for i in range(len(s)):
...    if s[i].isalpha():
...         print 'x'
...    else:
...         print s[i]
```